# Using scala cats to check combination of non-empty fields

Tags: scala, scala-cats

In my code i've a class that to check if it's valid i should eval if at least one of the possible field combinations exist (by exist i mean that each field of the combination should not be empty). Example:

```
case class Test( a: Option[String]
               , b: Option[String]
               , c: Option[String]
               , d: Option[String]
               , e: Option[Double]
               , f: Option[Double])
```

To be "valid", at least one of the following field combinations must exist ("a,b,c","a,d,e","a,f")

I was trying to do this with scala cats library but i'm kinda lost. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would just write a simple pattern match, since the set of combinations to validate is static and small.

Comment: so u want to validate that at-least one of the `option` `isDefined` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *validate* it you can just:

```
case class Test( a: Option[String]
               , b: Option[String]
               , c: Option[String]
               , d: Option[String]
               , e: Option[Double]
               , f: Option[Double]) {
  // "a,b,c","a,d,e","a,f"
  def isValid = (a.isDefined && b.isDefined && c.isDefined) ||
                (a.isDefined && d.isDefined && e.isDefined) ||
                (a.isDefined && f.isDefined)
}
```

If you want to make sure that you can only create it if one of field is defined you would have to use a smart constructor

```
sealed abstract case class Test private ( a: Option[String]
                                        , b: Option[String]
                                        , c: Option[String]
                                        , d: Option[String]
                                        , e: Option[Double]
                                        , f: Option[Double])
object Test {

  def create( a: Option[String]
            , b: Option[String]
            , c: Option[String]
            , d: Option[String]
            , e: Option[Double]
            , f: Option[Double]): Either[String, Test] =
  if ((a.isDefined && b.isDefined && c.isDefined) ||
      (a.isDefined && d.isDefined && e.isDefined) ||
      (a.isDefined && f.isDefined))
    Right(new Test(a, b, c, d, e, f) {})
  else
    Left("All arguments are empty")
}
```

Alternatively use ADT ensuring that one of fields is defined:

```
sealed trait Test extends Product with Serializable
object Test {
  final case class Case1( a: String
                        , b: String
                        , c: String
                        , d: Option[String]
                        , e: Option[Double]
                        , f: Option[Double]) extends Test
  final case class Case2( a: String
                        , b: Option[String]
                        , c: Option[String]
                        , d: String
                        , e: String
                        , f: Option[Double]) extends Test
  final case class Case3( a: String
                        , b: Option[String]
                        , c: Option[String]
                        , d: Option[String]
                        , e: Option[Double]
                        , f: Double) extends Test
}
```

You could use Cats here... but for what? You aren't combining a tuple or collection of Options into a single Option. You don't swap `F[Option[X]` into `Option[F[X]` or the other way round. There are no side effects, mappings, traversions, constructions of new objects from smaller objects embedded in some context, etc. You can try doing things like

```
implicit val booleanMonoid: Monoid[Boolean] = new Monoid[Boolean] {
  def combine(a: Boolean, b: Boolean) = a && b
  def empty = true
}
def isValid = List(a, b, c).foldMap(_.isDefined) ||
              List(a, d, e).foldMap(_.isDefined) ||
              List(a, f).foldMap(_.isDefined)
```

or maybe even

```
def isValid = (
  (a, b, c).tupled.void orElse (a, d, e).tupled.void orElse (a, f).tupled.void
).isDefined
```

but that is hardly any better than

```
def isValid = List(a, b, c).exists(_.isDefined) ||
              List(a, d, e).exists(_.isDefined) ||
              List(a, f).exists(_.isDefined)
```

achievable in vanilla Scala. I guess you could simply the notation by using some `Ring` defined on `Option[_]` to use `*` and `+`:

```
implicit val ring: Ring[Option[_]] = ... // yup, existential type here
def isValid = ((a * b * c) + (a * d * e) + (a * f)).isDefined
```

(which would require [typelevel algebra](https://github.com/typelevel/algebra)) but for using it in just one place I wouldn't see the gain.

Comment: Note that OP doesn't want at least one defined or at most one defined, he / she wants some combinations: `("a,b,c","a,d,e","a,f")` but, as I said (and you confirm), this hardly has anything to do with **cats**, just write the checks by hand at that is all.

Comment: Just noticed, fixing it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the cats `*>` operator to combine the fields you're interested in and test if the result is still nonEmpty. `a *> b` is a shorthand for `a.flatMap(_ => b)`.

```scala
import cats.implicits._

def isValid(t: Test) = 
  (t.a *> t.b *> t.c).nonEmpty ||
  (t.a *> t.d *> t.e).nonEmpty ||
  (t.a *> t.f).nonEmpty
```

But either way you could achieve nearly similar conciseness with `List(...).forall(_.nonEmpty)` without cats.

Comment: This doesn't work if OP wants that only `a` `b` & `c` to be defined for the first case.

Comment: But he didn't say only. He said at least one of those combinations. If it's exactly one of those combinations that should be defined, he should definitely parse them into an appropriate ADT asap.

Comment: Yeah that is why I said _"if"_ it is really not clear from the question what exactly OP wants. But just wanted to note it.